# What is a good solution to publish an asp.net mvc application. Many issues with VS2012 Publish tool

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, publish, msdeploy

I'm having a lot of issues with the Visual Studio 2012 Publish feature.

I am looking an easy way to publish my Asp.Net MVC 4 application. Today I have my development machine and a web server. Every time I update the application, I have to manually copy and paste the files I want. This is a very cumbersome work.

I have tried VS2012 publish tool and encountered so many problems.

1. I am properly configuring ftp to work on passive mode but VS2012 keeps saying that passive mode is not activated.
2. Since there is no "checkbox" to alternate from passive mode to normal mode, I had to modify the xml file no set it to not operate with passive mode.

The deployment now succeeds, and now I'm receiving the following error:

```
  c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
  Files\root\ee6c89b7\bf969ee8\App_Web_crjs1ytd.16.cs(33,0): 
  Error CS0234: 'The type or namespace name 'sistema_DocType' does not exist in the namespace 'gedaiapp.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

There is nothing wrong with my application on my local machine and I am able to build it and run in the web server when I copy/paste the files, I do now understand why it doesn't work when I use the publish feature.

I have already tried deleting all files in the  temp folder, cleaned the entire solution and project and rebuilt all.

Comment: Have you tried post-build event to copy/ftp your files instead of using *Publish*? This will copy every time you'll successfully build your project but as I understand that is your intention. And you'll also have complete control of which files should be copied (likely not configuration etc.)

Comment: I have not. I´ll try. Tks

Comment: BTW: You may include a text file in your project that lists all files to copy and use that file in your post-build step. This way it's easier to maintain the list of files and add new ones as required by your future extensions. Definitely easier to edit a text file than edit a post-build step. Let me know afterwards if it worked for you, so I can put it in an answer that you'll be able to accept.

Comment: If you are manually copying/pasting files to the server, why not just set your publish method to File System? I have not experienced any 'buggy' behavior with it.

Comment: @hawkke: he's trying to avoid this manual step and automate it.

Comment: There will be a passive mode checkbox in a future version. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Are you still getting an error? If so that please email me, my address is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not easy to answer because it is not know if this is an internal corporate environment or a small environment and you're just copying a few files over the internet to a single server.

If you're in an internal corporate environment and have a large number of files/servers you need to copy to, you may want to look at replication (3rd party software or homegrown application).

I'm with you in that the publish tool is not up to current standards.  My challenge with this tool is the lack of Secure FTP options for this application.  This should be standard with any version of Visual Studio.

I'm currently using the IIS SFTP and Filezilla (SFTP) for my transport needs as the alternative to the lack of encrypted features in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to hear that you guys are having issues. You are correct Visual Studio does not support SFTP, but we do support FTPS.

We have an item on our uservoice site for [SFTP support](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general-asp-net/suggestions/487960-secure-better-smart-client-publishing), but the vote count is currently very low (just has 6 votes). If you guys are interested in this support if you could vote on the item this will help me prioritize this so that we can investigate supporting this.

If you have any other feedback that you'd like to share with me regarding publishing please feel free to email me directly at sayedha[at]{MicrosoftDOTcom}.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Sayed. I´ll vote for that. I am working as a software developer for less than 6 months so I don´t even know what is the difference between SFTP and FTPS, but I´ll studie that and I be back if any question arise about publishing. Thanks again!

Comment: @GuilhermeLongo - Keep in mind that Web Deploy's preferred deployment method, WMSvc (over port 8172), supports HTTPS. If opening the port is an option, then it should help to meet your security requirements.